# Why does the OAuth Unauthorized Error (401) happen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, twitter, oauth-ruby

Sometimes an Twitter OAuth is successfully executed, but an unauthorized error is thrown. I get about 50 of these on a daily basis. It is worrying, because I have no idea how that might be reproduced.

What are the different cases where this error happens, and how can this be fixed or prevented?

Comment: Does it happen and then go away? Does it happen across a bunch of keys at once?  Is there any extra error messaging you get back? You probably need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has been having a lot of issues lately, 
also I have noticed to ensure good pass through i use HTTPS, and ensure my domain is api.twitter.com

and that remote path is using the /1/ prefix 
example: /1/statuses/update.xml